# Is it possible to make Lucene queries in alfresco that find nodes based on their parent/children properties

Tags: lucene, alfresco

is it possible to make Lucene query in alfresco that finds nodes based on their parent/children properties? For example i  want to find all the nodes that have the property "foo" set to '1' and have nodes associated to them by a child association with the property "baz" set to '2' (maybe specifing somehow the name of their child association)

something like

```
@crl\:numeroAtto:"6555" AND @crl\:firmatario:"Marco rossi"
```

Where "numeroAtto" is a property of the parent node and "firmatario" is a property of the child. The association type is "firmatari" (It's not in the query because i don't know how to use it)

To be even clearer i'm trying to tell lucene: "Find all nodes that have the property numeroAtto set to 6555 and that have children (association type with the children: firmatari) with the property "firmatario" set to Marco rossi.

Thanx in advance

Comment: (In the SQL world, this is known as an INNER or OUTER JOIN.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct lucene way to do this.

Another idea: the first would return all of the parent nodes and then build searches based on the root of each returned node.

Answer (score 5):

You can't search on associations, so what we do is not to build slow queries.
But add a new d:text property of the association on the parent Type.

So it's searchable through Lucune.
To make it fully working, create a Java Behaviour which checks on content update. And when 'your' association is found it adds it to the d:text property.

This way lucene searches are very quick.